# issue with R heatmap function - generates incorrect color scheme

Tags: r, heatmap

I've generated a simple test matrix of 0's and 1's only (just 3x3 matrix). The exact matrix I've generated is:

```
vector <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
matrix <- matrix(vector, nrow=3, ncol=3)
heatmap(matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA)
```

The heatmap that is generated then comes out with white, yellow, orange, and red blocks. How can just 0's and 1's generate blocks of such different colours? Shouldn't it just be say red and white? Or yellow and white? Or something like that?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just a tip, never call a variable 'matrix', or the name of any other function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior for `heatmap` is to scale values by row (center them and divide by the standard deviation). So you're not just plotting 0's and 1's in your example. Here's what you're really plotting

```
m1 <- sweep(matrix, 1, rowMeans(matrix))
msd <- apply(m1, 1, sd)
m2 <- sweep(m1, 1, msd, `/`)
m2[,3:1]

#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
# [1,] -1.1547005 0.5773503  0.5773503
# [2,] -0.5773503 1.1547005 -0.5773503
# [3,]  0.5773503 0.5773503 -1.1547005
```

If you were expecting just two colors, set `scale="none"`

```
heatmap(matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, scale="none")
```

This is all described in the `?heatmap` help page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great question. I would suggest reading the ?heatmap before posting. You can easily specify colors in the heatmap function as the following demonstrates:

```
vector <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
matrix <- matrix(vector, nrow=3, ncol=3)
heatmap(matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA,
        col = c('red', 'blue')
        )
```

If you want more control over the colors you can pass a function to 'col'.

Comment: But that would limit the available colors to only 2 shades. I'm using a test matrix of 0's and 1's, but the actual heatmap I would like to generate includes any number ranging from 0-100. My issue is not with the colour selection, but rather why the default palette seems to arbitrarily place colors that do not correspond to the numbers in my test matrix. 0 seems to be represented by both yellow and white, whilst 1 is represented by both orange and red. My question is why that is the case

Comment: A heat map where two identical values generate different colours makes me nervous to run the function on any actual data, which is why I'm sticking to a simpler test matrix of just 0's and 1's for now.